# Apache pekko ( akka http ) - Extracted string body from request doesn't have quote

Tags: json, request, akka-http

I'm POCing pekko http ( akka http ) for my next project.
I extracted json string from request body entity but it doesn't have quote on string value.

Code snippet on route dsl :

```
  post {
    path("account") {
      extract(_.request) { request =>
        val body = Await.result(request.entity.toStrict(1.second).map(_.data.utf8String), 1.second)
        println(body)
        complete(...)
      }
    }
  }
```

request : curl -X POST http://localhost:9090/account  -d '{"account":{"name":"TESTE"}}'
extracted json string : {account:{name:TESTE}}

Anybody know how to extract request body entity without removing quotes ?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you to do it this way, however blocking with Await is not a good practice when using akka-http. This also extracts the raw JSON string without removing the quotes:

```
  val jsonRaw: Route =
  path("jsonRaw")(
    post(
      entity(as[String]) {
        json =>
          println("JSON raw: " + json)
          complete(StatusCodes.OK)
      }
    )
  )
```

Working example:
https://github.com/pbernet/akka_streams_tutorial/blob/70e52e6e769a2779f1a6de744aab3cf4f16a3835/src/main/scala/akkahttp/SampleRoutes.scala#L121

To inspect the request on the server you may set these parameters in the application.conf in order to detect env issues.

```
pekko {
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  http.server.log-unencrypted-network-bytes = 100
  ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @earthling paul

I checked with your project and confirm that works.
But it still show same prroblem when I tested in my project.
So I tried with new project with just route code, but still removed quotes.

https://github.com/headiron/library_route_test

Request : curl http://127.0.0.1:6002/jsonRaw -X POST -d '{"TEST":"TEST"}}'
Console output : JSON raw: '{TEST:TEST}}'


Do you think any option need to be added ? 
I can't find any related config option and tried remove / add some libs but it doesn't helpful to resolve the problem.

Comment: Hmm, I am running your code using Java 11/21 on Windows and Mac and get the expected result. So it may be a difference in your env, eg the encoding. I have updated my answer with ways to inspect on the server.

Comment: Thanks @earthling paul for checking it.
You're right. I had tested with IDEA on Window, this issue was happening.
After your comments, I tested it using sbt on Linux and it works.

As you told, some env might affected problem and seems more digging the problem.

I'm sorry but one more question.
Is there any simple API ( not directive like entity(as[String]) ) to extract json string from request object? 
Await.result(request.entity.toStrict(1.second).map(_.data.utf8String), 1.second)
It is complicate just for extracting json string and we can't use entity(as[String])

Comment: Blocking with Await is not a good practice when using akka-http, but there is nothing stopping you to do it this way. If you like the answer above you may approve it

Comment: Added gist of comments to answer